# How to handle CSV files in this Python script

Tags: python, csv, operating-system, file-handling, nlp-question-answering

Using the CSV file of flowers again, fill in the gaps of the contents_of_file function to process the data, without turning it into a dictionary. How do I skip over the header record with the field names?

```py
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write("name,color,type\n")
        file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
        file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
        file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
        file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
        file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
    return_string = ""
    # Call the function to create the file 
    create_file(filename)

    # Open the file
    with open(filename) as file:
        # Read the rows of the file
        rows = csv.reader(file)
        rows = list(rows)
        # Process each row
        for row in rows:
            name, color, ty = row
            # Format the return string for data rows only
            if row != rows[0]:
                return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(name, color, ty)
    return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

After submitting my answer, the following message is shown:

```
Not quite, contents_of_file returned:
a carnation pink is
annual
a daffodil yellow is perennial
a iris blue is
perennial
a poinsettia red is perennial
a sunflower yellow
is annual

The output should be:
a pink carnation is annual
a yellow daffodil is perennial
a blue iris is perennial
a
red poinsettia is perennial
a yellow sunflower is annual
```

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Why is the desired output of the "red poinsettia" sentence split over two lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can skip a line by reading it in and discarding it before you instantiate the `csv.reader` object:

```
  with open(filename) as file:
    file.readline()  # header row
    for row in csv.reader(file):
      # do stuff
```

or you can just discard the first line by converting to a list and looping from 1:

```
  with open(filename) as file:
    for row in list(csv.reader(file))[1:]:
      # do stuff
```

or maybe like this if you want to loop over the iterator without loading all the rows into memory:

```
  with open(filename) as file:
    first = True
    for row in csv.reader(file):
      if first:
         first = False
         continue
      # do stuff
```

Or maybe you would prefer to use the dictionary form of the csv reader, so that instead of discarding the header row, you use it to provide dictionary keys:

```
  with open(filename) as file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(file):
      # row is now a dictionary, e.g.
      # {'color': 'pink', 'type': 'annual', 'name': 'carnation'}
      # do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as f:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(rows)
    # Process each row
    for row in rows:
      name, color, ty = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only          
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color , name, ty)

  return return_string

# Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as f:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    # Process each row
    line_count = 0
    for row in rows:
      name,color,typ = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only
      if line_count != 0:
        return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(name,color,typ)
      line_count += 1
    
  return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be complete code for above question using methods of module csv and os,

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as file:
    # discard/ignore header row
    file.readline()
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(file)
    # Process each row
    for row in rows:
      name,color,type = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color, name, type)
  return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(name, color, ty)
```

To

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color, name, ty)
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the question of " How do I skip over the header record with the field names?". One can use next():

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    headers = next(f)
    # do something with rest of the lines
```

Answer (score 0):

The required output format has to be typed in a proper sequence. I have tried this myself.

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(name, color, ty)
```

Edit this statement by switching the variables 'name' and 'color' format places.

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color, name, ty)
```

This would definitely work.!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
```

## Create a file with data in it

```
from typing import List

def create_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write("name,color,type\n")
        file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
        file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
        file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
        file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
        file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")
```

## Read the file contents and format the information about each row

```
def contents_of_file(filename):
    return_string = ""

# Call the function to create the file
create_file(filename)

# Open the file
with open(filename) as f:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(rows)
    # Process each row
    for row in rows:
        name, color, ty = row
        # Format the return string for data rows only          
        return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color , name, ty)

return return_string

# Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as f:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(rows)
    # Process each row
    for row in rows:
      name, color, ty = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only          
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color , name, ty)

  return return_string

# Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

import os
import csv

## Create a file with data in it

def create_file(filename):
with open(filename, "w") as file:
file.write("name,color,type\n")
file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

def contents_of_file(filename):
return_string = ""

```
# Call the function to create the file
create_file(filename)

# Open the file
with open(filename) as file:
  # Read the rows of the file
  rows = csv.DictReader(file)
  # Process each row
  for row in rows:
    color, name, type = row
    # Format the return string for data rows only          
    return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color" , row["name"], row["type"])

return return_string
```

## Call the function

print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/4733879) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations! Also your formatting is broken

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

```
import os
import csv
    
# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")
    
# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""
    
  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)
    
  # Open the file
  with open(filename, "r") as file:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.reader(file)
    # Process each row
    counter = 0
    for row in rows:
      name, color, ftype = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only
      if counter != 0:
        return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color, name, ftype)
      counter = 1
  return return_string
    
#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as f:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    # Process each row
    for row in rows:
      name, color, ty = row
      # Format the return string for data rows only
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row[color], row[name], row[ty])
  return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

and the output is this:

```
a pink carnation is annual
a yellow daffodil is perennial
a blue iris is perennial
a red poinsettia is perennial
a yellow sunflower is annual
```